# Different search results for e-commerce site

Tags: c#, java, oop

If i have to design a site which give different type of search criteria and it keeps on changing, is there some pattern i need to follow?.

For example, i have a search criteria to search by Category. Later on i decide to put an extra criteria to search by price. It can have combinations too for the above criteria. After some time i add one more criteria, search by location, but then i need to keep on changing the class that is returning me the result.

```
public List<Product> GetProducts(SearchCriteria search){
      //code
}


public class SearchCriteria{
     public string Category{get;set;}
     public double Price{get;set;}
}
```

So if i need to add another criteria, i need to change the SearchCriteria class and the GetProducts method.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good search platform provided by Apache known as [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

which comes with a java API known as [SolrJ](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj).

I think if you spend some time studying it, you will find your answer easily solved, plus you will be able to use some extra features provided by it.